# Need regex for danish phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to extract a danish phone number from a string. I got this

```
var phrase = "Text text text 11 22 33 44 text text.";
phrase = phrase.replace(/^((\(?\+45\)?)?)(\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})$/, "replace phone number");
alert(phrase);
```

I found this link, but it does not work:
http://www.dbsoftlab.com/etl-tools/regular-expressions/is-danish-phone-number.html

Comment: Good to see a former Sunderland goalkeeper delving into the world of web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expression you are trying to use, it will only match if the phone number is the only thing in the string, because ^ matches the beginning of the string and $ matches the end.

I believe that this is a much simpler regex that will work:

```
/([0-9]{2} ){3}[0-9]{2}/
```

So, you could say textStr.replace(/([0-9]{2} ){3}[0-9]{2}/g,'new string').

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `^` and `$`, which match the beginning and end of a string, respectively. Since the number is in the middle of the string, they don't match. Remove them, and it works:

```
> var phrase = "Text text text 11 22 33 44 text text.";
undefined
> phrase = phrase.replace(/((\(?\+45\)?)?)(\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})/, " replace phone number");
'Text text text replace phone number text text.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
/(?:45\s)?(?:\d{2}\s){3}\d{2}/
```

This maintains the optional country code that the prior regex has. I'm using non-capturing groups here for efficiency.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters